# PDF Format Error Creating On iSeries Using Workstation Customizing Object (WCST)

Tags: pdf, ibm-midrange

This is a weird problem and one that someone can hopefully give a clue on.

We are creating PDF's on the iSeries (OS version A7.1) overriding the printer output to a stream file specifying WSCST(*PDF).

The PDF's appear to be ok, Adobe Acrobat Reader has no problem dealing with them, however trying to import the PDF's into a PIM (Pimberly) there is an error saying that the PDF is invalid.

Running our PDF's through an online validator (the best I have found is https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf-tools/pdf-checker/), this gives a detailed report where the only error appears to be:

Fonts Results
Errors:
Uses Base 14 fonts not embedded in document:
Courier (1 instance)

I haven't been able to find anything on this and there are no options available on the WCST parameter when you select "*PDF". There are several Workstation Customization Objects, but the description of these doesn't indicate that using a different one would make a difference.

I wondered if anyone else had experienced a similar problem. We are on A7.1 and maybe there is a fix for this on A7.2 or above. We need a hardware upgrade to proceed though.

We do have software that will create PDF's (Catapult) but we are trying to create our PDF's on the iSeries as a preference.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is a PTF that "should" fix this, so providing the details here then will close the ticket.

"If an *AFPDS printer file or spooled file reference AFP fonts via the CDEFNT or FNTCHRSET parameter or keyword and TS1 is used to generate PDF output, the AFP fonts will not be converted to Type 1 fonts and embedded into the PDF."

The PTF details can be found at [https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/SE65280"](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/SE65280%22)